# I want to use LIKE operator with OR operator in Jpa Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I am retrieving books from database using three query parameters - name, author and description.
So, I am using the following method in BookRepository.

> public List<BookRepoRto> findByNameOrAuthorOrDescription(String name, String author, String description);

This is working fine. But suppose there is a book whose author is "Mahatama Gandhi". But while calling the method, user is passing the author's name as "gandhi"

> localhost:8070/api/bookstoreapp/books/nameorauthorordesc?name=gandhi

So, problem is that the method

> public List<BookRepoRto> findByNameOrAuthorOrDescription(String name, String author, String description);

is not working in that case. Same thing you can consider for description because obviously, user will not write whole description of the book in the query param to get the book he is thinking of because probably, he won't be knowing the exact description which is in the database.

So, I tried writing the following method instead of the upper one. In this method, I am trying to use the Like operator along with the Or operator but I am not getting the desired output. Please help!

> public List<BookRepoRto> findByNameLikeOrAuthorLikeOrDescriptionLike(String name, String author, String description);

I know that this problem can be solved using the @Query annotation but still I want to know if I can create the required jpa method which can fulfill the conditions :)

Comment: If your query starts getting to complex, you are always able to use the `@Query` annotation and make your own custom DB query.  See https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-query

Comment: Have you considered using Hibernate Search: https://hibernate.org/search/

Comment: @blurfus  yes, I have done it now using @Query(value = "SELECT * FROM books b WHERE b.name LIKE :name% or b.author LIKE %:author% or b.description LIKE %:description%", nativeQuery = true)
 public List<BookRepoRto> findByNameOrAuthorOrDescription(@Param("name") String name,@Param("author") String author,@Param("description") String description); ........... It is working fine but just wanted to know the jpa implementation for it if possible.

Comment: Did you consider the `IgnoreCase` postfix? It might help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use the `Like` operator you'll need to provide wildcards in the parameter. In order to get an equivalent query like the one you provided in the comments

```sql
SELECT * FROM books b 
WHERE b.name LIKE :name% 
or b.author LIKE %:author% 
or b.description LIKE %:description%
```

You should use

```
findByNameStartsWithOrAuthorContainsOrDescriptionContains(
    String name, 
    String author, 
    String description
)
```

See https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repository-query-keywords

Answer (score 1):

You can use the specification feature for this. It make you able to combine different predicates using FP-like style: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-criteria-queries